# How to tell Hibernate to not update certain columns

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I have an application that will give a user an opportunity to update certain values.  I want to send just the info on those columns to the user and take updates.

I'd like to persist a hibernate entity created from what they send to me, but not update the columns that the user does not have access to.  Likewise, if they request a new entry, I want to use the data they send me and set the unmentioned columns to the databases defaults.

Is there an easy way or best practice to use?

Should I create a second mapping to the table that just doesn't mention those columns?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think I will mark the property update="false"  on the mapping file.  I'd love to hear if there is a way to do it per persist, so if I wrote something else that should change those fields, it could do it.

Comment: update="false" doesn't work for my case :( 
EDIT: autially it does - it does not actually update in the DB but hibernate entity is read with modified incorrect field.

Answer (score 3):

Use updatable=false in Hibernate to avoid updating the column.

Eg:

```
@Column(name=CRE_TS, updatable=false)
private Date getCreTs(){
   return this.creTs;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want those columns to be updated, just don't call the setters of those columns? If the setter of a column isn't called (or called with a new value), the column won't be updated.

You need to fetch the entry with hibernate first, then call the setters for the appropriate columns and then persist it. That way, the data you don't want to be changed won't change.

Comment: I guess I could do that, but it's somewhat inconvenient.  

I need to take the data that the user gives me,  read the record out of the database, write a method to merge them, and then finally persist the record.

I guess considering that I'm using Hibernate, I'm getting off easy.  I've come to terms with Hibernate being extra work, but I wish it didn't involve extra I/O.

Comment: If something is managed on the DB side like a modified/created date with triggers, that data won't be available to hibernate without reselecting that entity. The point of updatable = false is to make hibernate not clobber DB generated field values.

Answer (score 0):

My requirement is i don't want to update the column in `method1()`, but it should be update in `method2()`, so in configuration level will not work here.

The solution is to make a `Cloneable` POJO and override `clone()` method.

```
public class User implements Cloneable {
//properties
@Override
    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return super.clone();
    }
}
```

**get Object From Session**

```
User user = <from Session suppose>.
User clone  = null;
try {
    clone = (User) user .clone();    // clone the real object
} catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
    //log your Exception here
}
clone.setUserName("Avinash");
    transaction.commit();
}
session.close();
```